# How to loop through file to copy into s3 bucket

Tags: bash

I have a file (file.txt) containing the absolute path

`cat file.txt`

#There are white space characters in the file name
/home/user/aws/doc/my doc 1.pdf
/home/user/aws/doc/my doc 2.pdf

```
IFS='' 
for FILE in $(cat "${file.txt}"); do

        echo "${FILE}"

        /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp ${FILE} "${S3Path_Bucket}PDF_FOLDER/"
done
exit 0
```

**When I ran the script I am getting an error below**

The user-provided path
/home/user/aws/doc/my doc 1.pdf
/home/user/aws/doc/my doc 2.pdf does not exist.

**I tried placing the escape character in file.txt**

/home/user/aws/doc/my\ doc\ 1.pdf
/home/user/aws/doc/my\ doc\ 1.pdf

**I get the same error**

The user-provided path
/home/user/aws/doc/my\ doc\ 1.pdf
/home/user/aws/doc/my\ doc\ 2.pdf does not exist.

**My file.txt is pretty big and I am trying to figure out how do I copy these files by escaping white space and in a loop.**

Thank you!

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't escape the white space, you quote your variables correctly. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for more info and copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net **as the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag you used already told you to do** then fix the issues it tells you about. Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Try this:

```
< file.txt xargs -I {} /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp -- "{}" "${S3Path_Bucket}PDF_FOLDER/"
```

or if you really want to use a loop then:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp -- "$file" "${S3Path_Bucket}PDF_FOLDER/"
done < file.txt
```